# Overlap date result in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate-search

I have two columns in database for date:

1. START_DATE
2. END_DATE

I am using range query to give the result. My query:

```
Query startDateQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField("eventsSet.startDate").above(java.sql.Date.valueOf(startDate)) 
                .createQuery();
Query endDateQuery = queryBuilder.range().onField("eventsSet.endDate").below(java.sql.Date.valueOf()) 
                .createQuery();
queryBuilder.bool().must(startDateQuery).should(endDateQuery).createQuery();
```

Its not giving the correct result.

I also want to return the overlap date as well. For example:
startDate=2020-04-07 and endDate=2020-04-14

it should return the records having in the range and also the overlap dates like a record having startDate=2020-04-01 and endDate=2020-04-15.

How to get it in Hibernate search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your query:

1. You're using `must` and `should` liberally. They are not the same thing.
   Basically:

   - if you want an "OR", create a boolean query with only "should" clauses. E.g. `queryBuilder.bool().should(subquery1).should(subquery2).createQuery();` means "subquery1 OR subquery2".
   - if you want an "AND", create a boolean query with only "must" clauses. E.g. `queryBuilder.bool().must(subquery1).must(subquery2).createQuery();` means "subquery1 AND subquery2".
   - if you want both "AND" and "OR", make sure to create a separate boolean query.
     E.g. `queryBuilder.bool().must(subquery1).must(queryBuilder.bool().should(subquery2).should(subquery3).createQuery()).createQuery();` means "subquery1 AND (subquery2 OR subquery3)".
2. You are not expressing the correct condition for an interval overlap. The correct condition is: `interval1StartDate <= interval2EndDate AND interval2StartDate <= interval1EndDate`

Comment: I have only two intervals startDate and endDate and here in condition you are using 4-intervals. I am converting interval1StartDate <= interval2EndDate AND interval2StartDate <= interval1EndDate expression to query as:
queryBuilder.bool().must(queryBuilder.range().onField("validFrom").above(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 7)))
.createQuery()).must( queryBuilder.range().onField("validTo").below(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 14))).createQuery()).createQuery(); which is wrong. How to map it on my case i.e with two intervals(startDate and endDate)?